# Updating nested state in React Redux, what is wrong with the syntax? Is there a better method of writing this reducer?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, redux, react-redux

I am trying to update this nested state called lobby. This is what 'lobby' looks like:

```
this.props = {
    lobby: [ 
        {
            id: 1,
            game: "Basketball",
            teams: 2,
            description: "Come!",
            filled_slots: 4,
            max_slots: 6,
            location_name: "cherry park",
            zipcode: "96024",
            active: true,
            eventDate: new Date(2018, 8, 20, 18),
            current_players_id: {
                 team1: [
                    1
                 ],
                 team2: [
                    2,
                    3,
                    4
                 ]
            }
        },
    {...},
    {...},
    ]
}
```

This is the update function I wrote so far to update teams, I'm having some trouble with the syntax in the return statement because I am using passed parameters. Any help or suggestions is much appreciated!

```
// Parameters passed to the reducer via action
gameId = 1
newTeams = { // passing newTeams to remove player from teams before adding
         team1: [
            1
         ],
         team2: [
            3,
            4
            ]
        }
 team = 'team2'
 userId = 2


// reducer
export const lobbyListReducer = ( state = intitialState, action = {}) => {
switch(action.type) {
    case JOIN_TEAM: 
        const { gameId, newTeams, team, userId } = action.payload;
        // console.log(action.payload)
        const lobbyIndex = () => {
            return state.lobby.findIndex(lobby => {
                return lobby.id === gameId
            })
        }
        // I have syntax errors below
        return {
            ...state, 
            lobby: [
                ...state.lobby, 
                state.lobby[ lobbyIndex() ]: {
                    ...state.lobby[ lobbyIndex() ],
                    state.lobby[ lobbyIndex() ].current_players_id: { 
                            ...newTeams, 
                            [team]: [ 
                                ...state.lobby[ lobbyIndex() ].current_players_id[team], 
                                userId
                            ] 
                        }
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    default:
        return state;
}
}
```

What is the correct way of passing parameters when using them to reference the nested levels in an Array of Objects?

Also is this data structure the best way to handle my data in state?

Comment: Have you considered using `Obejct.assign` to overwrite new values rather than creating an entirely new Object?

Comment: [Spread in object literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax#Spread_in_object_literals) is effectively the same as `Object.assign()` which the requester is already using through statements such as  `{ ...state }`

Comment: My reasoning is that instead of over using the spread operator and making a new object every time, he could just use one object assign function one time. This would allow him to mutate only the data that is vitally necessary within the state of the reducer with the data of the action being passed in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

lobby is an array, you can not use `state.lobby[ lobbyIndex() ]: {` to change element from an array. Also you dont need to change everything in one statement. Do in several steps. Build inner-most array first then next upper, then next, until you'll get final result.

like

```
const lobby = state.lobby[lobbyIndex()]
const newTeam = lobby.current_players_id[team].slice()
newTeam.push(userId)
const newLobby = {...lobby, ...{current_players_id: {...lobby.current_players_id, ...{[team]: newTeam}}}}
return {...state, lobby: newLobby}
```

Comment: This is a really good method of editting the properties within my state. However this method just adds more duplicate objects to my array, is there any way to make the objects unique in my array? I would add a filter to delete the duplicates after every insert but would that be overkill?

Comment: you can check if object already there and just dont add if it is.